# How to print vagrant's rsync timestamp and files changed?

Tags: rsync, vagrant

I am using Laravel Homestead VM via Vagrant.

I run Vagrant by

> vagrant rsync-auto --poll

At each file changed, it only prints

```
 ==> homestead-7: Rsyncing folder
    Exclude: [ ...]
```

However I would like Rsync to print **timestamp of the last update (file changed)** + **which files** were updated.

I am aware rsync set up is defined in .homestead/Homestead.yaml.
I have looked into the docs on vagrant website but couldn't find a proper solution.

**Homestead.yaml**

```
...
folders:
    - map: ~/__work/__homestead/Code
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/
      type: "rsync"
      options:
          rsync__args: ["--verbose", "--archive", "--delete", "-zz"]
          rsync__exclude: ["node_modules"]

...
```

Comment: Can you show us the contents of `Homestead.yamn`?

Comment: @schaiba question updated

Comment: I suggest you replace `--verbose` to `-vv` and check if that works.

Comment: It doesn't > Error: rsync: --vv: unknown option

Comment: `-vv`, not `--vv` - one dash.

Comment: result: no error, but no difference in the output (just which folder, but that was already before)